# Repair vs Optimize table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

1. Does Optimize include repair table or vice versa internally?
2. Is it possible to execute repair table only if found corrupt, any tools can support this?

(I am using MyISAM table engine)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `REPAIR TABLE` Fixes Table Corruption
  Issues, such as Open File Handle
  Counts, Resolution of Rows with
  Variable Length Data, and so forth.
- `OPTIMIZE TABLE` simply copies the
  table to remove unused space. If the
  table is MyISAM, `ANALYZE TABLE` is
  also performed to update index
  statistics for the sake of the Query
  Optimizer. If the table is InnoDB,
  `ANALYZE TABLE` is bypassed.

You could have mysqld auto check and repair all MyISAM tables.

In fact the book [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127), Section 30.5, Pages 444,445 state:

> The MySQL server can be instructed to
>   check and repair MyISAM tables
>   automatically. With automatic repair
>   enabled, the server checks each MyISAM
>   table when it opens it to see whether
>   the table was closed properly the last
>   time it was used and is not marked as
>   needing repair. If the table is not
>   OK, the server repairs it.
>
> To enable automatic MyISAM table
>   maintenance, start the server with the
>   --myisam-recover option, The option value can consist if a comma-separated
>   list of one or more of the following
>   values:
>
> - DEFAULT for the default checking.
> - BACKUP tells the server to make a backup of any table that is must
>     change.
> - FORCE causes table recovery to be performed even if it would cause the
>     loss of more than one row of data.
> - QUICK performs quick recovery : Tables that have no holes resulting
>     from deletes or updates are skipped.
>
> For example, to tell the server to
>   perform a force recovery of MyISAM
>   tables found to have problems but make
>   a backup of any tables it changes, you
>   can put the following lines in an
>   option file:
>
> [mysqld] myisam-recover=FORCE,BACKUP

You could also create a file called `/root/StartUp.sql` and put the `REPAIR TABLE` commands you want inside. Then add `init-file=/root/StartUp.sql` to `/etc/my.cnf` and restart mysql to trigger the init script.